# How do I respond to "Cheers" at the end of a conversation?

Tags: communication

How do I answer 'Cheers' at the end of an conversation? I say goodbye or cheers back but wonder if there is a better way. I'm American, talking to an Englishman.

Comment: What country are you in?  Is this only in verbal conversation, or in written conversation as well?

Comment: I am American and talk to an Englishman

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about general conversation and the English language, not about navigating the workplace as defined in the [help].

Comment: Hello Silvia and welcome to the Workplace. I've flagged this question as a better fit for english.stackexchange.com because it's about an idiom. A moderator is gonna have a look and handle the migration if needed. Cheers!

Answer (score 4):

In the UK, "Cheers" is normally said by way of thanks, so saying "Cheers" back might sound a bit odd, so you could respond with "No problem" (if you've resolved an issue or answered a question as part of this conversation).

It can also be "thanks for the conversation", or more of a "cheerio" type ending, depending on the context.

You could also end with "Goodbye", or "Have a good day", or words to that effect.

Or nothing.  It doesn't really matter.

But it's all in the context of the previous conversation.

Comment: Add _No worries_ to the list, depending on context

Comment: Cheers can also mean Goodbye.

Comment: How about *"Oh yeah, I loved that show!"*?

Answer (score 1):

Since 'Cheers' is normally used on an informal context, you can just come back with 'Cheers' as well (or 'Thanks' depending on the situation).

Also, personally, when this happens with written communication (e.g. e-mails) I sometimes answer with 'Best' (from 'Best Regards', but more informal).

Essentially, any not-too formal response should be appropriate.